# .Export cut-off Picture problem using VBA when try to use scroolbars

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize a chart to make it much bigger than the frame box that I am using to show it(Userform). In order to load the picture in the frame, I export the big chart to gif format, But excel is cutting the picture at the right every time I try to resize and add scrollbars.
Someone has already face that problem out there. I would appreciate a lot some help.

Comment: Do you mean that the save gif file is cut or that it is cut when you show it in your form?

Comment: the saved gif is exported already cut-off. then when I load it cames missing. I am struggling to work around this. But the chart itself is ok

Comment: essentially, the chart is a long seismic trace. So I am trying to make it visible. If it is too small it will be compressed and this is not good for view proposes. Can you help?